# How can I configure iPadOS so that any selected text is copied to the clipboard automatically?

Tags: ipad, copy-paste

E.g. the Google Chrome extension [Auto Copy 3.0.3](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg) can do it in Google Chrome for Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Got it, thx.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPadOS currently has no features so that any selected text is copied to the clipboard automatically. The applications on a non-jailbroken devices likely won't have enough permissions to do it as well.